# linux openvpn client connects to server but cannot access internet

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn

I have issues using openvpn on linux. I have tested it on a Windows virtual machine and it worked fine.
When connecting with linux, I can still ping IP addresses like "8.8.8.8" but cannot access web sites. The following server logs show up:

```
Fri Jul  8 10:48:41 2016 us=369113 client1/84.14.214.213:27118 TUN WRITE [51]
Fri Jul  8 10:48:41 2016 us=466396 client1/84.14.214.213:27118 UDPv4 READ [77] from [AF_INET]84.14.214.213:27118: P_DATA_V1 kid=0 DATA len=76
Fri Jul  8 10:48:41 2016 us=466751 client1/84.14.214.213:27118 MULTI: bad source address from client [192.168.19.82], packet dropped
```

I am using the exact same configuration on linux and Windows so i am guessing it comes from an external configuration on linux.

The ip "192.168.19.82" is supposed to be my Linux IP address on eth0.

Here are my client routes after connecting to the VPN:

```
root /home/user # ip r
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.19.254 dev eth0 
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.6 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
my_vpn_server_ip via 192.168.19.254 dev eth0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the split-tunneling, then please add the static routes for the internal subnets.
If you are using the VPN server as gateway and the VPN server will help to forward the packets to the internet, then please remove the following route entry and add the default route entry which is pointed to tunnel IP:

> default via 192.168.19.254 dev eth0

Also, please check if the DNS works by using nslookup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Removing the default ip route rule worked, I thought they were used in the order they were found.
Thanks for the help!